# Function to read a Python term (from within Python)?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

What is the name of the function that returns a Python value from a
string?  This would be the `Read` function that the interpreter uses for the 
[REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).  I'm 
looking for the Python equivalent of the `read` function that is available
in [Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm), 
[Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1), etc..  You can 
of course use `eval`, but that has the obvious 
downsides.  So I'm looking for the right/"safe" thing to replace `eval` in the 
snippets below:

```
assert( eval('True') )
assert( 123 == eval(' 123 #comments') )
assert( 'string' == eval('"string"') )
assert( [1,2,(3,4.0)] == eval('[1,2,(3,4)]') )
assert( {1:'spam', 2:'eggs'} == eval("{1: 'spam', 2: 'eggs'}") )
```

Comment: In case it is a literal, you can use `ast.literal_eval(..)`

Comment: Excellent.  It looks like `ast.literal_eval` is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for bool. It'll evaluate its argument as a boolean value. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool